# Changing ip address of exchange server 2007

Tags: exchange-2007, datacenter, consolidation

We've been planning to move our Exchange Server 2007 organization to a new data center. We're physically moving all our servers and assigning them new IP addresses.I've done literally all procedures for AD server.My question is : Are there any special concerns associated with changing the IP address of a working Exchange server?Will changing the IP addresses affect anything in the 2007 servers? if not is it enough to run the following command?

```
ipconfig /registerdns
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange doesn't care about the IP address. Therefore changing the IP address and rebooting the server will not be an issue. If you have any receive connectors on the 2007 server listening bound to a specific IP, be sure to change that as well.

Changing the name on the other hand would be a major problem, as that will break Exchange.